# Throwing a exception on Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a new webapi pattern and i decided use a new pattern to make my consistency.

I'm trying to set my error messages on the constructor of my class object `Pessoa`

```
public class PessoaModel
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string PessoaNome { get; set; }
    public string PessoaNomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string PessoaCnpjCpf { get; set; }
    public string PessoaEmail { get; set; }

    PessoaModel()
    {
        if (PessoaNome == null)
            throw new Exception("Preencha Nome");
        if (PessoaEmail == null)
            throw new Exception("Preencha Email");

        if (PessoaCnpjCpf == null)
            throw new Exception("Preencha Cpf ou Cnpj");
    }
}
```

Then the Exception happens but the Controllers continues running

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Pessoa")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(PessoaModel pessoa)
{
    if (_pessoa.Insert(pessoa))
        return Ok();

    return BadRequest("Pessoa não inserida");
}
```

Someone know how this work or if have a better way to do this?

Comment: Your constructor runs *before* anything can attempt to assign any values to your properties. It could never let anything pass.

Comment: The design you are trying to attempt fits where you r retrieving values from somewhere and then checking if the values are valid... Only then the values can have a chance be assigned properly. This way, your class can Never have any instance as the constructor itself fails downright

Answer (score 9):

What you are doing doesn't make sense. You are forcing properties to have a value, where you have done nothing to give them a value. At that time, they can only be set from the constructor.

Since you are using MVC/Web API, I would consider to use data annotations, to enforce the model to have the correct values.

```
public class PessoaModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required.")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
}
```

In your action:

```
if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Error"); // give an error, do something else
}
```